# Is it necessary to add reset.css for bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Please let me know, is it necessary to add reset.css or normalize.css in bootstrap 3 project?

Comment: No, it's not - but it's reset to Bootstraps' needs.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No，`bootstrap.css` includes `normalize.css` at the beginning of the file, and the `bootstrap-theme.css` file is optional according to the document.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you include all the boostrap framework is included. Be carefull if you build yours version, using only some elements, you have to include normalize.

Answer (score 1):

bootstrap documentation clearly states about it, they include normalize.css by default: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-normalize .

But [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) is standalone project, and good alternative to [Meyer's script](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), so you can use it separately.

Answer (score 0):

No, it already includes a Normalize.css which does the same thing.